# ffmpeg - Unrecognized option lavfi_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working with headphone filter command from official documentation - https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-20

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -lavfi-complex "amovie=azi_270_ele_0_DFC.wav[sr],amovie=azi_90_ele_0_DFC.wav[sl],amovie=azi_225_ele_0_DFC.wav[br],amovie=azi_135_ele_0_DFC.wav[bl],amovie=azi_0_ele_0_DFC.wav,asplit[fc][lfe],amovie=azi_35_ele_0_DFC.wav[fl],amovie=azi_325_ele_0_DFC.wav[fr],[a:0][fl][fr][fc][lfe][bl][br][sl][sr]headphone=FL|FR|FC|LFE|BL|BR|SL|SR"
output.wav
```

but I'm getting error

```
 Unrecognized option 'lavfi-complex'.
```

Here is my ffmpeg version info -

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-92377-g0c6d4e7ba4 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
libavutil      56. 23.101 / 56. 23.101
libavcodec     58. 39.100 / 58. 39.100
libavformat    58. 22.100 / 58. 22.100
libavdevice    58.  6.100 / 58.  6.100
libavfilter     7. 43.100 /  7. 43.100
libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
```

Comment: have you got any solution

Answer (score 1):

Those examples are malformed. I've pushed the corrections, but here's the correct form:

`ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter_complex "amovie=azi_270_ele_0_DFC.wav[sr];amovie=azi_90_ele_0_DFC.wav[sl];amovie=azi_225_ele_0_DFC.wav[br];amovie=azi_135_ele_0_DFC.wav[bl];amovie=azi_0_ele_0_DFC.wav,asplit[fc][lfe];amovie=azi_35_ele_0_DFC.wav[fl];amovie=azi_325_ele_0_DFC.wav[fr];[0:a][fl][fr][fc][lfe][bl][br][sl][sr]headphone=FL|FR|FC|LFE|BL|BR|SL|SR"
output.wav`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suspected that. I got it working this way but it does not give me the effect that this audio has - https://www.york.ac.uk/sadie-project/Resources/Binaural/Subject_002/TestAz.wav  from  - https://www.york.ac.uk/sadie-project/database_old.html. I thought it may be because it is the option in the question is having issues. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, not well-versed with binaural processing. Try the [sofalizer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sofalizer) filter, if you have the SOFA files.

Comment: I got sofa files from the same source but does not produce the effect. am I  missing something here? infact, it generates output of 0 bytes :(